# Android webview and Hebrew

Tags: android, webview

I have the following html code that I am trying to display in an Android WebView.

```
      <div id=header-right>
        <p  dir=RTL style='text-align:right;direction:rtl;unicode-bidi:
        embed'><a name=1><b><span lang=HE style='font-size:13.5pt;mso-fareast-font-family:
        "Times New Roman";color:#000099'> úôìú ùçøéú <o:p></o:p></span></b></a></p>
         </div>

         <div id=header-right>
         <p  dir=RTL style='text-align:right;direction:rtl;unicode-bidi:
         embed'><a name=1><b><span lang=HE style='font-size:13.5pt;mso-fareast-font-family:
         "Times New Roman";color:#000099'>îåãÆä  <o:p></o:p></span></b></a></p>
         </div>
```

The "weird" chars are hebrew. Both  display correctly in a browser (firefox), when run in Android, the first  displays correctly and the second displays incorrectly (the word is displayed inverted, first char last).

Both  have exactly the same structure. I do not understand why is shown correctly and the other not

Comment: So you're saying that the first displays RTL and the second is LTR?

Comment: Are you displaying these on the same page? or on different pages?

Comment: Yes, the first RTL, and the second is displayed LTR, both on the same page. The difference as Ted in the answer below states, that the second contains a vowel and the behavior is due to a software bug in the webview code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first word is unvowelized; the second has vowels (nikud). There is a [reported bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14661#c1) about this—vowelized Hebrew words are incorrectly laid out with letters going left-to-right (although, weirdly, words themselves are correctly laid out right-to-left).

You can test this diagnosis by removing the segol under the dalet in the second word (the only vowel) and seeing how it displays.